# int const MyClass::MyMethod vs const int const MyClass::MyMethod

Tags: c++, constants

Is there any reason to do `const int const` instead of just `String const`?

i.e., not using pointers.

Comment: Since `const String const` is not valid C++, I don't think there are any reasons to write it.

Comment: Fixed? I mean, it's just the concept I'm asking about...

Comment: Doubling up on `const` is not going to make any difference. And making a `const int` return value won't really make any difference, as you can't "use" the return value to modify anyway, that only works on `class` or `struct` types.

Comment: @ctote: as the question is now, you're asking if there's any reason to use `int` instead of `String`. Are you actually an `awk` programmer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're returning string from a function (e.g. const string MyClass::MyMethod), you're actually better off not using const since const will inhibit move semantics.  This exact issue was actually just discussed at one of Microsoft's conferences:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler

(The appropriate information is around the 35 minute mark)

Comment: Hm, so what about in the case of static strings?

Comment: As long as you are making a copy, it's not really important. `const string&` may be useful.